# How to make sure user is being authenticated from my app with POST request?

Tags: java, android, post

I am writing an android app that connects to my server with a POST request. So far, I am using SHA-256 to hash and salt epoch time and use that as a third parameter alongside the username and password to make sure that the authentication is done from the app. However, an attacker could decompile the apk and figure out the salt that I am adding to epoch time, allowing them to make a POST request from wherever.

I am wondering if there is a way to make sure the POST request is being made from my app. Note that I cannot change the authentication method of the server from POST.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `POST` is not an authentication method.  Read the rfc of HTTP to get info about authentication possibilities (there are many to show them in a comment)  Refs are:  HTTP protocol, RFCs [7230](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230), [7231](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231), [7232](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7232), [7233](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230), [7234](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7234) and [7235](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235).  The more interesting to you is [7235](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7235) (protocol authentication).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP Client authentication is an open process to allow vendors to implement different authentication schemes.

Apart from SSL (when run under HTTP protocol) having is own authentication mechanism (for servers and/or clients) the authentication task on HTTP protocol is managed by the `WWW-Authenticate` header in the HTTP header protocol.  That field reflects if the server demands some kind of authentication and how the peer is going to be authenticated.

This allows peer protocol authentication (not only for the client, but also the server can be authenticated) but it makes HTTP method agnostic, as the authentication procedure is orthogonal to the method used to request information. You can use authentication with any (or all) the http methods (GET, POST, CONNECT, HEAD, PUT, DELETE, etc)

You need to read the RFC's docs: [7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), [7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231), [7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232), [7233](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230), [7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) and [7235](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235).

The more interesting to you is [7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) (it describes protocol authentication), *and the documentation of the web server you are requesting to*, and how the service has been configured, to get an idea of the authentication methods it supports or the credentials you must provide to authenticate the client.

Normally, the process is as follows:

1. the client makes a unauthenticated request of info for the target url.
2. The server denies the request, signalling authentication must be used, and proposes an authentication method and challenge.
3. The client redoes the request, but providing the requested credentials from the server.
4. The server accepts the request or denies it again.

To note is that, depending on the authentication method to use (e.g. BASIC is a simple username/password scheme, while DIGEST forces the user to produce a digest, based on used credentials and some server provided info) you can need more than one roundtrip to the server (the server can force you, while not common, to use two of these in chain to grant you access to the resources)

In the case of Java, probably a good source of documentation is the *Apache HttpClient* class, and it has some tutorials from Apache that show you how to make authenticated requests.  A good reference is [this](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/index.html).